# Missing template arguments before '(' token in adder_cpu.cpp

Tags: ipu

I am new to IPU and I am running the [tutorials](https://docs.graphcore.ai/projects/bow-pod-getting-started/en/latest/programs.html#running-a-program-on-the-bow-pod) from the graphcore.

When I run the second step to compile the program, I got the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6WHy.png).

Is anyone experienced with the IPU and graphcore know how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a small bug in SDK2.6. If you edit line 48 of adder_cpu.cpp as follows:

```
eng.readTensor("output", gccs::ArrayRef<float>(results));
```

then it should work.

The ipu version should compile already using:

```
make adder_ipu
```